# How to take arrowhead function as argument for a regular function?

Tags: javascript

so im new to java script and i'm working on a new project where I'm trying to create a function like map that takes a function and applies that function to every element in an array. The difference with mine is that I also need to take in a function as an argument but I also have to take in integers that represent indexes that I need to 'skip' or that the function doesn't apply to. For example:

```
const bb = [1, 23, 22, 36];

// pass a function to mapCSE and index to skip
const new_a = bb.mapCSE(x => x + 2, 0, 2);

console.log(new_a);
// expected output: Array [1, 25, 22, 38]
//notice that index 0 and 2 were skipped, the function was not applied to them

// pass a function to mapCSE and index to skip
const new_new_a = bb.mapCSE(x => x + 10, 1);

console.log(new_new_a);
// expected output: Array [11, 23, 32, 46]
//now only index 1 was skipped
```

I was wondering on how I could take a arrow function or a function in general and take it as an argument. And also, how would I apply such function to every element in my array? Here is my general thought process so far:

```
//how do i use length and access member of array im calling for mapCSE //function
function mapCSE(function(x,y,z){return x+y+z}, ...arguments){//taking in unlimited number of arguments and a function
  let validIndex = new Array();
  for(let i = 0; i<arrayTest.length;i++){//loop to find and store valid indexes to skip
if(arguments[i] < 0 || arguments[i] > arrayTest.length){//checking if the argument is a valid index to skip
  validIndex[i] = i;//storing valid index to skip later
}
  }

  for(let i = 0; i<arrayTest.length;i++){//loop to apply or skip function
if(validIndex[i] == i){
  continue;// increment i to skip index and proceed to next element
}else{
  /*
x is current value of element
y is value of current index
z is original array
  */
  arrayTest[i].function(x,y,z){return x+y+z};
  /*
  this is where I would need tips on how to properly apply the argument function to the current element in array
  */
}
  }//end of for
}///end of function
}///end of function
```

So do you guys think I'm heading in the right direction? Any advice/help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is perfectly ok, but there some areas you may improve upon.

Since you are calling `mapCSE` on `bb` as a method of the object, you need to add the `mapCSE` to the prototype of `Array`.
Since `arguments` is already built-in JS, it confuses the reader (though the code works fine). So better is to replace it with some other name as `indices`.

```js
Array.prototype.mapCSE = function (mapper, ...indices) {
  const len = this.length
  // result array of same length as input array
  const result = new Array(len)
  
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    // the current element of the input array
    const el = this[i]
    // the element of the result array
    // it remains same if `i` is in the indices to skippedd
    // or the function is applied, otherwise
    const resutlEl = indices.includes(i) ? el : mapper(el, i, this)
    // assign the element of result array
    result[i] = resutlEl
  }
  
  return result
}

const bb = [1, 23, 22, 36]

// pass a function to mapCSE and index to skip
const newA = bb.mapCSE((el, idx, array) => el + idx + array[0], 0, 2)
console.log(newA)
```

### Time complexity analysis

N - length of input array
M - no of indices to skip
Time complexity - `O(NM)`

It can be further reduced to - `O(M log M + N)`. Let me know if you wish to do that.

Comment: Wow thank you so much. I was wondering how to call mapCSE that way and since my array wasnt an object I was confused on how to execute it exactly.I have one more question for you if you dont mind, ive been stumped on this well, how could i make mapper  take in 1 to 3 arguments? Either way I appreciate your answer, thank you!

Comment: Please depict the scenario in the question of what you wish to do. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: const new_a = bb.mapCSE(function (x, y, z){
return x + y + z[0];
}, 0, 2, 15);
console.log(new_a); I tried mapper.call(el,i,this.Array) and it didnt work. I think im not understanding how to use callback.call properly or thihs is not the right way to do it.

Comment: So basically i modified what you gave me a little bit:  const resutlElement = indices.includes(i) ? currentElement : mapper.call(currentElement,i,this.Array). I want to take in the current element which is x, the current index, which is y, and the current array which is z

Comment: @Aviera00 update the answer! There is no need for `.call`. You can directly pass the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead of `map`, or simply use foreach:

```
const bb = [1, 23, 22, 36];
const indexes = [0,2];

function excludeElement(arr, arrayOfIndexes) {
    for(elem in arr) {
        // if current index is not in the array of indexes
        if (arrayOfIndexes.includes(elem) ) {
                    bb[elem] = bb[elem] + 2;
        }
    }
    console.log(arr);
        return arr;
}

excludeElement(bb, indexes);
```

if you use `for` with the `in` word, `elem` becomes also the index of `arr`; this way you can use `arr[index]` to indicate the content of a specific element of `arr`.

Comment: This is changing the array in-place. I think the asker wants to return the new modified array though they have not mentioned it explicitly. Tthe mapper can be a custom function. Ergo, `bb[elem] = mapper(bb[elem])` would be more correct.

Comment: if this is the issue he can simply make a copy of the original array and launch the above function, instead of re-writing an entire function like `map` only for passing a new parameter. Anyway, if this is what he wants, sure, your answer is better.